# Does the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with at least one rational coordinate have measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with at least one rational coordinate have measure zero? I can show easily that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ has measure zero, but this is only easy because $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is countable.

There are uncountably many points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one rational coordinate and one irrational coordinate, how do I show that this set has measure zero?

Comment: Can you show that lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are Lebesgue measure-zero? Then your set is simply a countable union of measure-zero sets, which is again measure-zero. (For this, even you don't need the full power of the former claim. It is sufficient to show that lines that are parallel to one of the axis have measure zero. As a hint for this, for each $\epsilon > 0$ notice that $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-2^n, 2^n] \times [-\epsilon/4^n, \epsilon/4^n]$.)

Comment: @SangchulLee A good hint. I personally really like drawing a sombrero instead, instead of having to draw boxes.

Comment: Yes, that works. I can show that, thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure how you chose the tags on this question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Haha sorry, I was wondering at first if this set was countable, which it of course isn't. That was on my mind when I chose the cardinality/topology tags, sorry about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set is equal to $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q})$. Try to show that each of these sets has measure zero; in fact, you may find it much easier to just prove the result that

$$A \text{ countable } \implies \mathcal{L}^2 (A \times \mathbb{R}) = 0.$$

Drawing a picture of this is a good start - $A \times \mathbb{R}$ consists of countably many lines, and a line can be fit inside a region of arbitrarily small area.